# Piping wget into curl

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I'm piping wget output into curl. Running it from terminal where all variables are correctly replaced by correct values exit code is 0

```
wget -O - $DOWNLOAD_URL | curl -H "Authorization:token $TOKEN" -H "Accept:application/vnd.github.v3+json"  -H "Content-Type:application/zip"  --data-binary @- "https://uploads.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo/releases/$RELEASE_ID/assets?name=$NAME.zip"
echo $?  # 0
```

Running it inside a script in a subshell where also all variables are correctly replaced
and the status code is 127 plus error message "No such file or directory"

```
$( wget -O - $DOWNLOAD_URL | curl -H "Authorization:token $TOKEN" -H "Accept:application/vnd.github.v3+json"  -H "Content-Type:application/zip"  --data-binary @- "https://uploads.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo/releases/$RELEASE_ID/assets?name=$NAME.zip" )
echo $?  # 127
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(command)` is the syntax for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). It means to execute the command, and then substitute the output back into the command line. It's usually used for arguments, e.g.

```
printf "%3.2f" $(some command)
```

In your case, since you don't have a command before it, it will try to execute the output of the `curl` command as a shell command. So unless the web page you're downloading is a valid shell command, you'll get an error when it tries to execute the output.

If you just want to execute a command in a subshell, but not do command substitution, just use parentheses without `$`:

```
( wget -O - $DOWNLOAD_URL | curl -H "Authorization:token $TOKEN" -H "Accept:application/vnd.github.v3+json"  -H "Content-Type:application/zip"  --data-binary @- "https://uploads.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo/releases/$RELEASE_ID/assets?name=$NAME.zip" )
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - at the end it turned out that I did not need subshell ;-) but now I'm aware of the difference